# System.AccessViolationException when debugging x86 C# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, x86

My client uses a third party tool (PDFLib) for dynamic PDF generation. There is an x64 version of the DLL that runs on a website and an x86 version that runs on a background processor which is a 32-bit console application written in C#. It must be a 32-bit console application because the client VMs that the application runs on are 32-bit.

My local machine is a 64-bit machine with Windows 8.1 and I am running Visual Studio 2013 Professional although I have also tried Visual Studio 2015 Professional.  The solution targets .Net Framework 4.5.1. The relevant code is below.

```
PDFlib p = new PDFlib
p.set_parameter("errorpolicy", "return");
p.set_parameter("license", "my_license");

if (p.begin_document("", "") == -1) 
{
    //some error handling
}
```

At the p.begin_document call I receive a System.AccessViolationException.  I tried setting my Solution Platform to x86.  I have tried targeting framework 4.5.2.  I have put it back to 4.5.1 and uninstalled later versions of the framework. I have restarted my machine for each of these changes. None of this has had any affect.

This does not happen when debugging the x64 version in the web project. This does not happen in the compiled version of the x86 Console Application. This **only** happens when **debugging** the x86 Console application. What can I do to avoid this error while debugging?